# Saltstack - Schedule to ensure service is running not working

Tags: service, scheduler, schedule, salt-stack

I'm trying to set up a Saltstack schedule that will check to ensure that a service is running on the minion. However, it doesn't seem like `service.running` is working as a function on the schedule.

Here's my `run.sls` file:

```
test-service-sched:
    schedule.present:
        - name: test-service-sched
        - function: service.running
        - seconds: 60 
        - job_kwargs:
            name: test-service
        - persist: True
        - enabled: True
        - run_on_start: True
```

And I execute the following: `salt 'service*' state.apply run`

This ends up with the following error on the minion:

```
2017-03-28 02:47:11,493 [salt.utils.schedule                                            ][ERROR   ][6172] Unhandled exception running service.running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/utils/schedule.py", line 826, in handle_func
    message=self.functions.missing_fun_string(func))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/utils/error.py", line 36, in raise_error
    raise ex(message)
Exception: 'service.running' is not available.
```

I haven't seen anything in the documentation that says I can't run `service.running` from a schedule. Is it a known limitation of Salt? Or am I just doing it wrong?

I can use `cmd.run`, but it ends up spamming the logs with errors if the service is already running.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was pointed in the right direction on the Salt Google Group. There's a difference between execution modules and state modules. Since `service.running` is an execution module, and schedule only supports state modules, I had to reference it indirectly. I used 2 files:

schedule.sls:

```
service_schedule:
  schedule.present:
    - function: state.apply
    - minutes: 1
    - job_args:
      - running
```

running.sls:

```
service_running:
  service.running:
    - name: test_service
```

Now, running `salt 'service*' state.apply schedule` did exactly what I wanted it to.